# Format Date field type

Tags: php, mysql

i have a csv file that i'm interest and the date format is 20-Nov-2010 how do I format it for insertion into mysql accepted format for a field with Date as its type?

Answer (score 0):

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("20-Nov-2010"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Andreas' answer is a bit terse - in PHP this will return a string which you can splice 
into your query:

```
$d=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("20-Nov-2010"));
$qry="INSERT INTO sometable (adate) VALUES('$d')";
```

But if you omit the punctuation, you can ad it without the quotes:

```
$d=date("Ymd", strtotime("20-Nov-2010"));
$qry="INSERT INTO sometable (adate) VALUES($d)";
```

A drawback of this approach is that strtotime() tends to always return some sort of date value - and sometimes not what you expect.

However you could do the parsing in MySQL, which is a lot more strict:

```
 $d='20-Nov-2010';
 $qry="INSERT INTO sometable (adate) VALUES(STR_TO_DATE($d, '%d-%b-%Y'))";
```

But remember to [check for errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html) when mysql tries to parse the date.